# PyQt continue stopped upload and terminated thread - gets stuck

Tags: multithreading, pyqt, python-requests

I have an application, which communicates with some API to upload data.

It has ExportDialog, which has ProgressBar.

The algorythm is the following:

- In MainWindow I select Path to sql db and click **Export**
- Db data get stored in list
- Appears ExportDialog with button **Start**
- When I click **Start**, QThread task and upload start off.
- Along with **Start** becomes **Stop** and the button **Break** appears
- If I click **Stop**, the upload process stops and the QThread task termitates and **Stop** becomes **Start**. Program saves the current value of the last list's index, so when I click **Start** again, QThread task starts and upload continues where It was left off.
- If I click **Break**, the StatisticWindow appears, which shows the result

Sometimes, internet connection can be lost, so I have the **try...except** block, which catches requests's ConnectionError.
My problem is that sometimes it gets stuck if the internet connection is lost.

Let's show it in code.
**ExportDialog**

```
class ExportDialog(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, table, api):

        super(ExportDialog, self).__init__()
        self.table = table
        self.stat = list()
        self.value = 0
        self.task = WorkThread(self.table)
        self.length = len(self.table)
        self.api = api
        self.initUI()
        self.retranslateUI()
        self.initActions()
```

**WorkThread class**

```
class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):

    punched = QtCore.pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __init__(self, table, index=0):
        super(WorkThread, self).__init__()
        self.table = table[index:]

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        for i in self.table:
            self.punched.emit(i)
            time.sleep(1)

    def stop(self):
        self.terminate()
```

**ExportDialog.initActions**

```
def initActions(self):
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.changeTask)
        self.breakButton.clicked.connect(self.task.stop)
        self.breakButton.clicked.connect(self.close)
```

**ExportDialog.changeTask**

```
def changeTask(self):
    if self.sender().text() == "Start":
        self.startButton.setText(self.tr("Stop"))
        self.breakButton.show()
        self.setWindowTitle(self.tr("Processing..."))
        if self.value > 0:
            self.task = WorkThread(self.table, self.value)
        self.task.punched.connect(self.onProgress)
        self.task.start()
    else:
        self.task.stop()
        self.startButton.setText(self.tr("Start"))
        self.breakButton.hide()
```

**ExportDialog.onProgress**

```
def onProgress(self, i):
    try:
        row = i
        word = row.get('word').lower()
        context = row.get('context', '')
        translate = self.api.get_translate(word)
        self.api.add_word(translate['word'],
                                translate['tword'],
                                context)
        if translate['is_exist']:
            result = "Exist"
        else:
            if translate['tword'] == "No translation":
                result = "No translation"
            else:
                result = "New"
            self.api.substractMeatballs()
            meatballs = "Meatballs: {}".format(self.api.meatballs)
            self.meatballs_label.setText(meatballs)

        self.stat.append({"word": word,
                          "result": result,
                          "tword": translate['tword']})

    except ConnectionError:
        self.startButton.click()
        # this is where WarningDialog should be shown
        # but in my case it happens 50/50
        warning = WarningDialog("No Internet Connection")
        warning.exec_()
        return
```

api - API instance, which has:

- **auth** method - simple authorization through **requests**
- **add_word** method - simple POST request through **requests**
- **get_translate** method - simple GET request through **requests**

__

If I manually click **Stop** and then **Start**, everything goes well.
If I manually drop the internet connection, something weird happens.

- Sometimes, it goes as expected - WarningDialog shows up and the task gets stopped. I can continue from where it was left off
- Sometimes it just gets stuck - nothing happens, MainWindow is frozen, ExportDialog isn't responsible - can't click either **Stop** or **Break**
- Sometimes it opens up over 100 instances of WarningDialog and the whole system gets stuck

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Every time `changeTask` is invoked, `task.punched` connects to `onProgress` slot one more time. This means the slot will be invoked multiple times on each `task.punched` signal.

When error happens inside that (`onProgress`) slot, `startButton` is clicked. At first everything is OK: the button's text is "Stop", so it simply stops the task. But the slot fires multiple times, right? The second time is different: the text of the button is "Start" now, it connects `task.punched` with `onProgress` once again and starts the task, which will eventually call `onProgress`... Meet the infinite recursion.

```
def changeTask(self):
    if self.sender().text() == "Start":
        [...]
        self.task.punched.connect(self.onProgress) # <--
        self.task.start()
    else:
        [...]

def onProgress(self, i):
    try:
        [...]
    except ConnectionError:
        self.startButton.click() # <--

        warning = QtGui.QDialog()
        warning.exec_()
        return
```

The сonclusion:

- To fix the bug, connect the signal to the slot only one time 
  (move `self.task.punched.connect(self.onProgress)` from `changeTask` to `__init__`)
- Maybe it's not a great idea to have one button for many purposes. Wouldn't it be better to create two buttons (for starting and stopping) and show only one of them?

Comment: I see where the infinite loops appears but get it just to some extinct.
To continue stopped process I have ```if self.value > 0:
                self.task = WorkThread(self.table, self.value)```, so every time ```self.task``` is completely new, right? Why is it get connected with onProgress one more time?

Comment: @GriMel, self.value is always 0, you do not assign any other value to it.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the code for a bit and now it works

**WorkThread**

```
def __init__(self):
    super(WorkThread, self).__init__()

# new method
def getData(self, table, index=0):
        self.table = table[index:]
```

**so, in ExportDialog init**

```
self.task = WorkThread()
self.task.getData(table)
```

**punched** sent to **initActions**

```
def initActions(self):
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.changeTask)
        self.breakButton.clicked.connect(self.task.stop)
        self.breakButton.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.task.punched.connect(self.onProgress) # <-- Here we go!
```

**and in changeTask**

```
def changeTask(self):
    if self.sender().text() == "Start":
        self.startButton.setText(self.tr("Stop"))
        self.breakButton.show()
        self.setWindowTitle(self.tr("Processing..."))
        if self.value > 0:
            self.task.getData(self.table, self.value)
        self.task.start()
    else:
        self.task.stop()
        self.startButton.setText(self.tr("Start"))
        self.breakButton.hide()
```

Thanks to **Alexander Lutsenko** for giving me the right way